# How to upgrade the GPG version installed on AWS EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2, gnupg

I have a requirement to upgrade the GNU Privacy Guard(GPG) package installed on AWS EC2 instance. The OS installed on EC2 is Linux(Not Ubuntu).
The current version installed is **2.0.22-5.amzn2.0.4**,which is depricated as per GPG website. https://gnupg.org/download/index.html

Hence, I wish to upgrade it to version 2.3

I tried the below commands for the purpose.

1. $ sudo yum update-minimal gnupg
2. $ sudo yum reinstall gnupg
3. $ sudo yum update gpg

Everytime, I get a message saying **NO PACKAGEs MARKED FOR UPDATE**

When tried to reinstall using command number 2, the same version **2.0.22-5.amzn2.0.4** is reinstaled again, which actually isn't the latest version.

Can anyone suggest the process to upgrade to latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Updated remark:

The package name on Amazon Linux 2 should be gnupg2.

---

You should be using Amazon Linux 2, you are using the latest package version provided by Amazon Linux 2.
By the time I write this answer, most distribution are still using gnupg 2.2, the only common distribution providing gnupg 2.3 is Fedora, you can find it at https://fedora.pkgs.org/35/fedora-x86_64/gnupg2-2.3.2-2.fc35.x86_64.rpm.html

In case you really need it now, you may either:

1. Build it by yourself
2. Install the rpm package from Fedora via `dnf install <rpm-url>`

Comment: I am already using Linux 2. However, by default the gpg version installed in 2.0.22

Comment: Give a shot with `yum update gnupg2`